# Can I install both RTX 2080 ti and GTX 1080 ti on same machine

Tags: gpu

I have a spare 1080 ti GPU, can i install it along with RTX 2080 ti on the same machine?

Will it be effective in rendering?

Comment: This question is too broad and not 100% Blender related.

Comment: Blender can use both GPUs simultaneously for rendering with Cycles. Whether or not you're able to install it in your mainboard and if the PSU provides enough power is unclear from the provided information.